# Regular $15$-gon with colored vertices isomorphic to $D_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider a regular 15-gon in which every third vertex is painted red. Show that the symmetry group of the painted 15-gon is isomorphic to $D_5$.

Attempt: I have tried making a regular 15-gon and painted every third vertex red. I noticed that I can make a regular pentagon if I connect the red vertices. Can I say that the inscribed pentagon is a subgroup of the 15-gon, and therefore isomorphic to $D_5$?

Please, any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you paint every third vertex of a $15$-gon, you are actually fixing some pentagon. Thus any isometry of the $15$-gon preserving the pentagon is an isometry of the pentagon.

Moreover, the pentagon contains three non-collinear vertices and any isometry of the plane is completely determined by what it does to those three points.

Thus, no two isometries of the $15$-gon can give rise to the same isometry of the pentagon, so that the subgroup of those preserving the pentagon is indeed isomorphic to $D_5$.

Answer (score 0):

How many ways can you rotate the 15-gon and have the red vertices line up? How many ways can you reflect it and have the red vertices line up? How do all of these symmetries interact with each other?